# How do i get the value of size attribute as XXL? As I want to display a div if size of product is XXL

Tags: magento-1.9

```
<ol class="product-grid">
            <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
                <li class="product-grid_item product-tile">
                    <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
                                            <div class="quickview"><button class="button button--s button--inverted">Quick View</button></div>
                        <picture class="pimg1">
                            <source srcset="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(290, 290); ?>" media="(min-width: 400px)">
                            <img srcset="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(130, 130); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel($product, 'small_image')); ?>">
                        </picture>
                                                <picture class="pimg2">
                            <source srcset="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(290, 290); ?>" media="(min-width: 400px)">
                            <img srcset="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(130, 130); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel($product, 'thumbnail')); ?>">
                        </picture>
                        <?php

                        // GravDept:
                        // Check if product is new.
                        $isNewProduct = Mage::helper('magefrontend')->isNewProduct($product);
                        ?>
                        <?php if ($isNewProduct): ?>
                            <ul class="badge-list">
                                <li class="badge-list_item badge-list_item--new">
                                    <?php echo $this->__('New'); ?>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </a>
                                        <div class="product-banner-box">
                                                    <span class="plussize-banner">now in plus sizes</span>
                                        </div>
```

Comment: I want to display last div only if size of the product is also XXL

Comment: are you using custom options or configurable products?

Comment: Yes, My size attribute is custom ,and itis for all type of products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing below code

```
<div class="product-banner-box">
    <span class="plussize-banner">now in plus sizes</span>
</div>
```

With

```
<?php
$showMessage = false;
$tmpProduct = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($product->getId());
    foreach ($tmpProduct->getOptions() as $o) {
        if($o->getTitle() == 'Size'){ // Use Your Size Option Title
            $values = $o->getValues();
            foreach ($values as $v){
                if($v->getTitle() == 'XXL'){ // Use your option text to match
                    $showMessage = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
<?php if($showMessage): ?>
    <div class="product-banner-box">
        <span class="plussize-banner">now in plus sizes</span>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'  :(

Comment: Please check updated code. There was a type extension

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::getId() in

Comment: This solution should work, but it's better not to use `$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_product->getId());` in a product grid, because then the entire product info will be loaded, for each product in the grid. Better make sure the value is present in the collection.

Comment: @shushant, please check updated answer

Comment: Thanks but its not working bro...:(

Comment: @SushantThorat, did you use your custom option title in place of `Size`? Make sure you are not using `Sizes` or any other text as title of the custom option.

Comment: Hey..its working..!!:)